# Process has been terminated due to Stack OVerflow exception while copying sheet into another workbook

Tags: syncfusion

We are using "Syncfusion.XlsIO.Base" 15.4460.0.20, we are trying to copy worksheet of one excel file into another excel file. But while copying the file, it is throwing Stack OverFlow exception.

Below is our code

```
  using (ExcelEngine excelEngine = new ExcelEngine())
                {

  //Open an existing workbook.
  IWorkbook workbookMonthly = null;
  workbookMonthly = excelEngine.Excel.Workbooks.Open(monthlyReport);

  IApplication application = excelEngine.Excel;
  application.DefaultVersion = ExcelVersion.Excel2013;
  IWorkbook reportWorkbook = application.Workbooks.Create();                                       
  reportWorkbook.Version = ExcelVersion.Excel2013;

   for (int i = 0; i <= 1; i++)
      {                                              reportWorkbook.Worksheets.AddCopy(workbookMonthly.Worksheets[i],ExcelWorksheetCopyFlags.CopyAll);
      }
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue is raised based on the worksheet data in your source document. So, it will be more easier to analyze, if you could share the below information

1. Total rows and columns used in the worksheet including blank cells
   with formatting.
2. The type of data in the source workbook such as conditional
   formatting, named range, formulas, table, pictures and so on.
3. The stack trace of the exception.

I work for Syncfusion

Comment: I upgraded to latest version, it has fixed issue